# javascript and divs, creating images and paragraphs in divs.

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to do some basic stuff with javascript, to get it to generate some website content automatically,, but its driving me crazy!!! Could someone please show me a simple example of how to do get javascript to create new images and paragraphs in divs.. lets say my website structure is like this...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div id ="wrapper">
<div id ="content">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html
```

how would I use a javascript function to create images and paragraghs in the "content" div on-loading the page and also on-clicking an image. I know it has to with the DOM but Ive been at this for hours and I just cant get it to work! Please show me an example of how its done. Thanks a lot in advance!!!!!!

Comment: What have you tried? You wrote you did try, then show us, maybe you're just missing a comma? or maybe you didn't try? show us...

Comment: Take a look at this article: [Adding elements to the DOM](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml). Ive created a example based on your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/GCVGg/

Comment: Oh I tried allright!! I stsrted with a js file with arrays of the info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In its simplest form:

```
// gets a reference to the div of id="content":
var div = document.getElementById('content'),
    // creates a new img element:
    img = document.createElement('img'),
    // creates a new p element:
    p = document.createElement('p'),
    // creates a new text-node:
    text = document.createTextNode('some text in the newly created text-node.');

// sets the src attribute of the newly-created image element:
img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people';

// appends the text-node to the newly-created p element:
p.appendChild(text);

// appends the newly-created image to the div (that we found above):
div.appendChild(img);
// appends the newly-created p element to the same div:
div.appendChild(p);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wNJWu/).

References:

- [`element.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3adocument.createTextNode).

Comment: Works like a charm and a great example to learn from. Thank you very much.